# False .52 over x-axes in pspicture

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, pspicture

I was trying to make a pspicture with custom labels on the x-axes. Unfortunately the value, I am trying to let the y-axes start with, is displayed above the x-axes. 
Does anybody know why?

```
\documentclass[border=0bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[](-1,-2)(1,1)
        \psaxes[xLabels={1}](0,0)(-1,-1.52)(1,1)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pspicture with wrong '.52' displayed]

Comment: What's the `xLabels={1}` option supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

With `xlabels={...}` you cannot have an axes length of an integer, e.g.

```
\psaxes[xLabels={1}](0,0)(-1,-1)(1,1)
```

then the labels defined by `xlabels` are printed from the left in steps of `dx` to the right. This is valid to both axes indepenedent of an existing `ylabels={}`! With your

```
\psaxes[xLabels={1}](0,0)(-1,-1.52)(1,1)
```

only the -1 is taken as value and `.52` as normal text.